# Value of type 'string' cannot be converted and property is readonly

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

Already asked this question in bitcoin stackexchange but it may not get answered for days or maybe never so trying here and its related to something basic I need to do related to initialization of variables in vb.net

Maybe noob question but important for me to understand how to pass value from a textbox or string to something else which is 'bob.PubKey' in this case

```
Imports NBitcoin

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim bob As New Key
        Dim alice As New Key
        Dim satoshi As New Key

        Dim redeemScript As Script = PayToMultiSigTemplate.Instance.GenerateScriptPubKey(2, {bob.PubKey, alice.PubKey, satoshi.PubKey})

        Label1.Text = redeemScript.Hash.GetAddress(Network.TestNet).ToString
        'Console.WriteLine(bob.PubKey)


    End Sub
End Class
```

NBitcoin: https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin

Answer (score 0):

EDIT-------------------------------------------------

Hrm... nope. Don't do that.

Changing the PubKey is not straightforward. The PubKey property has only a Getter, no Setter, so you can't just spawn a new one with the content you want, and changing the existing one's content isn't an option either.

I may be wrong as I'm not used to `nBitCoin`, but it seems to me that you're not supposed to switch the pubKey on the fly. Your only option would be to instantiate a new `Key` with your brand new PubKey, but the new key won't automatically share all the properties of the current key and thus could cause unexpected behavior.

The PubKey is created automatically when you need it, and it's value is not supposed to be messed with.

*(There may be a way to do it through the class in the Secp256k1 folder, but this is deep enough for me to say that there must be a better way to tackle this issue.)*

---

### Original answer which was the wrong way around

You can normally use an [assignment operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_assignment_operators.htm) for this kind of operation, like `Textbox1.text = bob.PubKey`, but the problem is that `bob` is a Key class, not a String, and `.PubKey` is a PubKey class, not a String either.

I'm not acquainted with `NBitcoin` but I'm willing to bet that you can do this:

```
Textbox1.text = bob.PubKey.ToString()
```

and it'll show the key, or at least a String representation of the key. The thing is, this may not be usable in other contexts, not in the same way that you can use the whole `bob` object.

I just took a look at the source code and it seems that it should work just as I guessed. It should be the exact same result than doing

```
Textbox1.text = bob.PubKey.ToHex()
```

Have fun!

Comment: This is the opposite of what I am trying to do. There is a Textbox, User enters a string in it at run time, it should be used in the calculations as bob.PubKey

Comment: Sorry I got this mixed up, I'll take a second look at it.

Comment: @Boboshi I updated the answer with some new informations, but no good news.

Comment: Thanks I have asked for help from dev who created NBitcoin